# Is there a way to find same values in a set

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, duplicates, computation-theory

This is the algorithm I currently have, which runs in O(1) time but uses n^2 number of cores:

```
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   for j = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
      if (A[i]>A[j]) or (A[i]=A[j] and i>j) then
         wins[i] = 1;
      else
         wins[i] = 0;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   A[wins[i]] = A[i];

for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   if win[i] == win[i - 1] or win[i] == win[i + 1]
      return true
   return false
```

Comment: What's your machine model?

Comment: Can you have more than one duplicate?

Comment: What's the purpose of 

    `for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel A[wins[i]] = A[i];` ??

Comment: What's the behavior of the CRCW PRAM when writing different values ?

Comment: Can you use n/2 processors to hash each number from 0 to n/2, and then n/2 processors to do the comparisons for each hash? Some details need working out about the communication, but that should be O(1) expected time. (It also needs hash in O(1) time, so you'd need to clarify the machine model as DE asks).

Answer (score 1):

On an CRCW machine, you can very well perform all comparisons and write if true.

```
result= false;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   for j = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
      if A[i] == A[j] then
         result= true;
```

Doing with less processors seems difficult, as the result of a specific comparison gives you little information on the other comparisons unless you use transitivity to deduce new relations. Transitivity can be exploited by forming "chains" of doubling sizes, but I don't see how this could be done in constant time.

---

It the stored values are integers limited to the range `[1,n]`, you can use an histogram:

```
result= false;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   H[i]= 0;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   H[A[i]]++;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   if H[i] > 1
      result= true;
```

This assumes that a concurrent ++ is available. If not, you can instead use an auxiliary array where you store `i` at the location of `A[i]`, assuming that a concurrent write results in one of the values being written. Then in a second pass, you check if another `A[i]` is also there.

```
result= false;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   B[i]= 0;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   B[A[i]]= i;
for i = 0 to n-1 do in parallel
   if B[A[i]] > 0 and B[A[i]] != i
      result= true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the fact that all values are between `1` and `n`.

Assuming a PRAM and concurrent write and concurrent reads.

```
dup = false
for i = 1 to n do in parallel
    if (A[abs(A[i])]) < 0 : dup = true; stop;
    A[abs(A[i])] = - A[abs(A[i])]
return dup
```

The way this fictional memory will handle concurrent writing is not clear.
I assumed the the memory will handle it, by serialising the writing.
This is a new solution, that take it into account more precisely.

```
dup = false
for i = 1 to n do in parallel
    k = A[i]
    A[k] = - A[k]
    If (A[k]) > 0 : dup = true; stop;
return dup
```

Here is another version, in case there is still uncertainty about how the memory works:

```
for i = 1 to n do in parallel
    k = A[i]
    A[k] = 0
dup = false
for i = 1 to n do in parallel
    If (A[k]) !=  0 : dup = true;
return dup
```

Note: In all proposals, I assumed that all reading `k = A[i]` are performed prior to all writing.

Comment: I use `abs(.)` to handle the fact that `A[i]` could have been set to a negative value by another processor. But if all first operations are performed in parallel `k = A[i]` and then `A[k] ...`, use of `abs(.)` is not necessary. See the second version.

Comment: This code does not make sense. If all tests are performed simultaneously, no A is ever negative. And otherwise, the result can be random.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Writing at the same location occurs when a duplicate exists. I assume that this theoretical memory is able to manage concurrent writing, by serialising the different writings. This is commonly done with real memory (think to the C++ `atomic` for example). The result will not be affected by the fact that one particular access is performed before the other.

Comment: You missed my comment. 1) if all processes perform the first statement, nobody stops (and on the second round, everybody stops !). 2) serialized writings can lead the complexity to O(n).

Comment: @YvesDaoust The problem is that how memory works here is not clearly defined. I modified the function to be more resilient. Concerning point 2, I pay attention to stop the whole process as soon as a dupe is detected, to avoid it.

Comment: No, if the concurrent writes are serialized, they cannot be done in constant time.

Comment: The new code is better. One must make sure that A[0] is accessible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I assumed 1-indexing to simplify the code. And I assumed that all reading `k = A[i]` were performed prior to all writing ...

Comment: @Damien: the last condition is mandated. Deserves to be said.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Done. Thanks for your help.